# Azure B2C authorize loop in sub-application

Tags: iis, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I'm currently using Azure B2C to authenticate a series of .NET 6 server-side Blazor apps and Web APIs. In IIS, the apps are setup as follows:

domain.com

- domain.com/admin
- domain.com/api1
- domain.com/api2
- domain.com/api3

If a user logs into domain.com and then navigates to domain.com/admin, /admin gets caught in an infinite authorize loop with Azure B2C. Then, if you browse back to domain.com and logout, you can navigate back to /admin and currently be signed in.

However, if you log into /admin first and navigate to domain.com, you will be successfully logged in. Then, if you navigate back to /admin, you get stuck in a auth loop again.

I have verified that the only difference between the 2 access tokens is the audience and the timestamps issued (of course). In B2C, I have both web applications set to accept access tokens from any app authorizing with the B2C domain.

I have also tried setting up my cookies with settings from here: [Cookie Sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Any help/guidance I can get would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:

Logging into domain.com then logging into /admin causes the loop. Then, if I log out of domain.com and navigate back /admin, the loop stops and I'm authenticated.

Dev tools show zero errors and from what I can tell in code, it appears like I am authenticated.

EDIT 2:

I noticed that some of the B2C samples had the following code that I was missing:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
});
```

I added this code and that seems to have fixed the login loop portion. However, when I call the following:

```
    await TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { ApiSettings.UserScope });
```

I receive the following error:

```
False MSAL 4.40.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.3 Microsoft Windows 6.3.9600 [2022-04-20 15:01:50Z - 31ac7d51-15e1-424a-8be1-1eb09a6cbf82] Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException
, ErrorCode: user_null  
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am attempting to obtain a token for calling a downstream API.

Comment: Use the browsers developer tools - network trace to see what, if any, errors are being returned. Errors might be found in the 302 redirect location, or response body to your app. Usually an error causes the app to try with you again, creating this looping effect.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Already did that. No errors anywhere. Access token is validated and the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider is called. I can't find an error anywhere.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.